# Mongoose modify single field from .find() response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to modify the result of a single field from .find() to remove unnecessary data.
The field `likedBy` (array) should return an empty array when it doesn't contain the userId. But, when `likedBy` does contain the userId, it should return the array with only that userId, instead of all userIds.

```js
const response = await MyObject.find().lean({
    "likedBy": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$eq": body.userId
        }
    },
});
```

Current response when userId = 'id-1':

```json
{
    "_id": "some id",
    "...rest of the fields"
    "likedBy": [
        "id-1",
        "id-2",
        "id-3",
    ]
},
```

What I want:

```json
{
    "_id": "some id",
    "...rest of the fields"
    "likedBy": [
        "id-1",
    ]
},
```

Comment: why not this `.forEach(doc=> doc.likedBy.includes(body.userId) && doc.likedBy=body.userId);` appended to your call. You'll be sending a few more bits though. But tbh this is probably faster.

Comment: That would absolutely work but I thought it would be better to do it directly using mongoose when possible.

Comment: Alright, it's up to you. To me you just need a simple solution. The pipeline tends to be slow. But the more solutions, the better.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an `aggregate` pipeline and use `$filter` to only return the matched array element:

```
YourModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "likedBy": body.userId
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      likedBy: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$likedBy",
          as: "likedBy",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$likedBy",
               body.userId
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      otherField: 1         
    }
  }
])
```

Here's an example on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TevNq_QW6uc).

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is nearly how I want it. If I'm using it correctly then this returns nothing when userId isn't a match (e.g. when userId = 'id-10') while I'd like to still return all objects with all fields and only the likedBy field as null or an empty array when userId can't be found.